# Find subarray that sums to given value in Python

Tags: python, recursion, sub-array

If I am given a subarray [1,2,3,4] and a value 8. I want to return the subarray [1,3,4]. I have a bug in my code and am not sure how to fix it since I am new to recursion. I have my Python code below. I am getting back the value [3,4] to print which is obviously not the correct answer. How do I get my first element in the array?

```
def main():
    s = 0
    a = [1,2,3,4] # given array
    sa = [] # sub-array
    w = 8 # given weight
    d = False
    d, sa = checkForWeight(a,w,s,d,sa)
    print sa

def checkForWeight(a,w,s,d,sa):
    l = len(a)
    s += a[0]
    sa.append(a[0])
    if s == w:
        d = True
        return d, sa
    else:
        try:
            d, sa = checkForWeight(a[1:],w,s,d,sa)
            if d != True:
                d, sa = checkForWeight(a[2:],w,s,d,sa)
            else:
                return d, sa
        except:
            sa = [] # i put this here because I want to erase the incorrect array
    return d, sa
```

Comment: Not related to your question: Use the values `True` and `False` (boolean values) instead of the strings `'True'` and `'False'`.

Comment: Also not directly related: you always use a[0] as part of the solution. What if the solution does not include it?

Comment: You're right! I should add that into my function when i first call it.

Comment: A few critiques aside from where you are going wrong. You are feeding your function many parameters, it would be better to use a class with class or instance variables, so that you don't have so many parameters.  Your code would be clearer if you named your variables things that make sense, eg call 'w' weight instead of putting a comment next to it; this is especially true of the first local variable of checkForWeight. It is best to avoid using lower case 'l' and upper case 'o' as they are easily confused with 1 and 0.

Comment: Also passing mutable types (like lists) to a function and then changing them is really confusing here and not needed in your implementation

Comment: What do you mean? what mutable array?

Comment: You keep changing `sa`. It changes the original `sa` if you use append

Comment: If I do not pass it i get an error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sa' referenced before assignment

Comment: You can pass it just don't change it. Use a tuple not a list.

Comment: BTW, I know I've dealt with this problem elsewhere on SO.  I can't find the prior questions any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a recursive solution that works, hope it helps:

```
def main():
    success, solution = WeightChecker((1,2,3,4)).check(8)
    print solution

class WeightChecker(object):
    def __init__(self, to_check):
        self._to_check = to_check
    def check(self, weight):
        return self._check((), 0, weight)
    def _check(self, current_solution, index_to_check, remaining_weight):
        if remaining_weight == 0:
            return True, current_solution
        if index_to_check == len(self._to_check):
            return False, ()
        current_check = self._to_check[index_to_check]
        success, solution = self._check(current_solution + (current_check, ), index_to_check + 1, remaining_weight - current_check)
        if not success:
            success, solution = self._check(current_solution, index_to_check + 1, remaining_weight)
        return success, solution
```

(The dynamic programming approach is better as keredson suggested)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need **any** subarray that matches your sum?  or **all** subarrays?  (Or the shortest, or the longest?)  The proper answer is going to be highly dependent on this.

BTW, this is a varient of the knapsack problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Also, your recursive strategy appears to be factorial in complexity.  (If it were for a code test, this alone would likely fail the applicant.)  I'd highly suggest a dynamic programming approach.

**EDIT**

If you need all possible, you're looking at an NP problem.  I'd recommend focusing on ease of implementation/maintenance rather than absolute performance to show off your skills.  For example:

```
import itertools

def find_all_subsets_that_sum(elements, total):
  for i in range(len(elements)):
    for possible in itertools.combinations(elements, i+1):
      if sum(possible)==total:
        yield possible

print list(find_all_subsets_that_sum([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 10))
```

Is not the absolute fastest (you could do a lot of pruning in a self-rolled recursive solution), but it'll be the same big-O as whatever more complicated solution you come up with.  (All solutions will be dominated by the O(n choose n/2).)  Very few interview candidates will respond with something like:

> This is not as fast as it can be, but it's within spitting distance of the fastest, and would likely be the best ROI on developer hours, in both implementation and maintenance.  Unless of course the data set we're parsing is huge, in which case i would recommend relaxing the requirements to returning a heuristic of some number of solutions that could be calculated with a O(n^2) dynamic programming solution."

And you can use that to stand out.

Comment: This is indeed similar to the knapsack problem. I need to find all possible subarrays. I believed that recursion would of been the easiest way. I want to find an answer and then implement a better way.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that you append a[0] to sa at the top of the function, but later destroy that with the return value from a sub-call.  To patch this, add a clause before you return the final result:

```
    except:
        sa = [] # i put this here because I want to erase the incorrect array
if d:
    sa = [a[0]] + sa
print "Leave: drop", d,sa
return d, sa
```

I do recommend that you follow the recommendations in the comments: instead of passing so much stuff around, concentrate on local control of partial solutions.

Try a solution two ways: with and without the current element.  Your recursive calls will look something like this:

```
sa = checkForWeight(a[1:], w)         # Solutions without first element
    -- and --
sa = checkForWeight(a[1:], w-a[0])    # Solutions using first element

You don't have to return a success flag; if **sa** is None or empty, the call failed to find a solution.  If it succeeded, in the **w-a[0]** call, then you also need to prepend each solution in **sa** with **a[0]**.
```

Does this get you moving?